# how can i get Web Analytics database name with Object Model?

Tags: object-model, web-analytics, database-connection

First let me say, that all of we doing in sharepoint is base on the object model, so i can go to Central Administration and get my "Web Analytics Service Application" Database Name and Server Name, and my question is how can i do it with the Sharepoint Object Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function below (edited, will not compile) get the Web Analytics connection for given SPSite

/// 
        /// get Connection string to Web Analytics database
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        public static string GetWAConnectionString(SPSite site)
        {
            string sConnectionString = "";
            //get web analytics proxy type
            SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
      bool islocalservice = false;
            try
            {
                foreach (SPServiceApplicationProxy pro in site.WebApplication.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup.Proxies)
                {
                    string s = pro.GetType().ToString();

```
                if (s == "Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Administration.WebAnalyticsServiceApplicationProxy")
                {
                    SPIisWebServiceApplicationProxy iispro = (SPIisWebServiceApplicationProxy)pro;

                    Uri endpoint = iispro.ServiceEndpointUri;



                    foreach (SPService svc in farm.Services)
                    {


                        if (svc.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Administration.WebAnalyticsWebService" && svc.Applications.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (SPServiceApplication app in svc.Applications)
                            {
                                string svid1 = app.Id.ToString();
                                if (!islocalservice)
                                {
                                    //ServiceEndpointUri    {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:510a8bf612714e58a3077f0a1f09ac1d#authority=urn:uuid:3ff1d34f9e994f939ebee8df59ff77b5&authority=https://irene2010rtm:32844/Topology/topology.svc}
                                    islocalservice = endpoint.AbsolutePath.ToLower().EndsWith(svid1.ToLower().Replace("-", ""));
                                    if (islocalservice)
                                    {
                                        Type objectType = app.GetType();
                                        PropertyInfo WS = objectType.GetProperty("WarehouseSubscriptions");
                                        if (WS != null)
                                        {
                                            object o = WS.GetValue(app, null);
                                            if (o != null)
                                            {
                                                string sDatabases = o.ToString();
                                                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                                                doc.LoadXml(sDatabases);
                                                if (doc.ChildNodes.Count > 0 && doc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                                                {
                                                   // WarehouseSubscriptions:   "<ReportingDatabases><ReportingDatabase>Irene2010RTM;WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_ReportingDB_0682c2f1-c019-4e1e-939f-2c0c1a6ea381</ReportingDatabase></ReportingDatabases>"
                                                    string sDb = doc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;

                                                    string[] props = sDb.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                                                    if (props.Length >= 2)
                                                    {
                                                        //get Web Analytics databases
                                                        SPDatabaseService dbService = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<SPDatabaseService>();
                                                        // Enumerate the service instances
                                                        foreach (SPDatabaseServiceInstance instance in dbService.Instances)
                                                        {
                                                            if (instance.Status == SPObjectStatus.Online)
                                                                // enumerate the databases within this service instance
                                                                foreach (SPDatabase database in instance.Databases)
                                                                {
                                                                    object oDB = database.GetType();
                                                                    // If the objects type is "Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Administration.WebAnalyticsWarehouseDatabase", you've found the Web Analytics DB.
                                                                    if (oDB.ToString().CompareTo(@"Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Administration.WebAnalyticsWarehouseDatabase") == 0)
                                                                    {
                                                                        if (database.Server.Name.ToLower() == props[0].Trim().ToLower() && database.Name.ToLower() == props[1].Trim().ToLower())
                                                                        {
                                                                            //after much trouble we found a database
                                                                            sConnectionString = database.DatabaseConnectionString;
                                                                            LoggingUtil.WriteTrace(TraceLevel.Info, "Analytics ConnectionString found:" + sConnectionString, Switch);


                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                    }



                                                }

                                            }
                                        }


                                    }

                                }


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LoggingUtil.WriteTrace(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Warning, "Cannot get WA connection:" + e.ToString(), Switch);
        }

        return sConnectionString;
    }
```

Comment: fantastic man if it works you just saved the day, thanks.

Comment: that's worked just fine. how you came upon with this?